# Getting elements from array based on property values (AngularJS)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach, properties, push

I have an array of players, each player is an object that has a number of properties, one is "goals".

```
var players =    [  
       {  
          "id":"4634",
          "name":"A. Turan",
          "number":"0",
          "age":"28",
          "position":"M",
          "goals":"1"
       },
       {  
          "id":"155410",
          "name":"H. Çalhano?lu",
          "number":"0",
          "age":"21",
          "position":"A",
          "goals":"0"
       },
       {  
          "id":"4788",
          "name":"B. Y?lmaz",
          "number":"0",
          "age":"30",
          "position":"A",
          "goals":"2",
       }
    ]
```

I've written a function to cycle through the array and push every element that has more than '0' goals to an array, `topScorers`. Like so:

```
$scope.topScorerSearch = function() {
  var topScorers = [];
  $scope.teamDetails.squad.forEach(function(o) {
      if (o.goals > 0) {
        topScorers.push(o)
      }
    });
  return topScorers;
}
```

With the function called as `{{topScorerSearch()}}`.

This returns only players who have scored. Perfect.

**However**, I want to run this on other properties, which will result in a lot of repetitious code. How can I make this a general purpose function that can be executed on different properties?

I tried including the 'prop' parameter, but it didn't work:

```
$scope.topScorerSearch = function(prop) {
  var topScorers = [];
  $scope.teamDetails.squad.forEach(function(o) {
      if (o.prop > 0) {
        topScorers.push(o)
      }
    });
  return topScorers;
}
```

...and called the function like this:

```
{{topScorerSearch(goals)}}
```

Why doesn't this work? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should accept the answer that solves the problem so others can glance and see it is resolved (also @Sidriel gets their points).

Comment: I was going to... It was only 3 minutes ago, give me a sec :)

Comment: Patience isn't my thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `prop` will not resolve to `goals` because `goals` is being treated as a variable with a null or undefined value, making prop null or undefined.

If you use the alternative way of accessing object properties `object["property"]` and use the function `{{topScorers("goals")}}` it should work out.

Comment: Tried it, and no joy. First I switched the dot notation to square brackets and that worked fine, but then I again tried applying the parameter to the function, and the argument to it's call, and nothing...

Comment: Sorry... my mistake. I'd applied the square brackets to the expression and the function, but didn't put the property in the function call. D'oh. Thanks for your help.